# Wake up MCU on UART RX data

Tags: embedded, uart, low-power

I have several MCU's of which I cannot use the deep-sleep modes, because they cannot wake up on UART data coming in. Are there any components for sale which can solve this? I can imagine something that delays the RX line for a fraction and toggles an GPIO on data arrival, which I can use the wake up the MCU.

Comment: Which MCUs are they?

Comment: If for some reason you can't use the RX line pin as a GPIO wakeup interrupt, you could also run the signal into an additional pin which can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Just to clarify Chris Stratton's comment. During sleep you could configure the RX line as a GPIO and then enable an interrupt on that line when it's a high to low edge (as would be the case when UART data is sent). With this you can detect when data is being sent and reconfigure the pin for UART, although it might take a bit for UART to initialize once this is done (since you wakeup and have to start clocks). So, make sure you have some redundancy (you might lose a byte, for example).

Comment: Which MCUs and Also at what baud rate?

Comment: @LeonHeller / Swanand: LPC 11Uxx series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any MPU with pin change interrupts should allow this. Some (MSP430 at least) can wake in a microsecond and start timing the start pulse  right away. But even if your micro can't wake up fast enough, can you transmit an extra character at the start of the message to wake it up?

If you give us a clue which MCU you mean, someone might have a more appropriate suggestion.

The datasheet for the [LPC11U1x](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC11U1X.pdf) says

(page 2)

> Up to 8 GPIO pins can be selected as edge and level sensitive
>   interrupt sources.

(page 14)

> USART
>      RXD ... PIO0_18 ...

so the UART RX pin is also a GPIO pin (PIO0_18 on some packages)

(page 18)

> Any GPIO pin providing a digital function can be programmed to
>   generate an interrupt on a level, a rising or falling edge, or both.

(page 26)

> The LPC11U1x can wake up from Deep-sleep mode via reset, selected GPIO
>   pins, a watchdog timer interrupt, or an interrupt generating USB port
>   activity.

The [User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10462.pdf) says
(page 35)

> 3.5.33 Pin interrupt select registers Each of these 8 registers selects one GPIO pin from all GPIO pins on both ports as the source of
>   a pin interrupt. To select a pin for any of the eight pin interrupts,
>   write the pin number as 0 to 23 for pins PIO0_0 to PIO0_23

(page 38)

> 3.5.37 Interrupt wake-up enable register 1 This register selects which interrupts will wake the LPC11Uxx from deep-sleep and power-down
>   modes. Interrupts selected by a one in these registers must be enabled
>   in the NVIC (Table 58) in order to successfully wake the LPC11Uxx from
>   deep-sleep or power-down mode

So it looks feasible. One remaining question is how fast you can get out of deep sleep in the interrupt handler and restart the UART. I'll take a wild guess and say fast enough.

Comment: It's an NXP LPC11Uxx, Cortex M0 MCU. And I cannot add extra characters at the start, since I dont control the peripheral that is sending the data.

Comment: According to AN11027 it takes 56 μs to get out of deep sleep, so at my baudrate (115200) I will miss the first characters.

Comment: You'll miss about half a character then. Unless the UART is allowed to run while the GPU is in deep sleep. Look into whether that is possible.

Comment: Alternatively : does the peripheral implement HW flow control? If so, interrupt on RTS using above approach, and set CTS when you are fully awake.

Answer (score 0):

If the micro is really unable to wake-up from whatever sleep mode you are in based on UART RX traffic, there probably is a dedicated I/O pin that is capable of waking the micro from deep sleep.  You could tie the two pins together (UART RX and I/O pin) and then you would wake up from deep sleep.  I've never seen a micro that didn't have some I/O pin or peripheral that could wake it up from every sleep mode it had.  Otherwise it's not really a sleep mode so much as a death mode.

If you can't recoup any pins, you could probably set the micro to wake-up periodically based on a timer overflow (depending on your baud rate) and check the state of the pin, but now we're getting into ugly solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Many processors can wake up when an input changes, including the UART receive pin, but cannot wake up fast enough to ensure correct reception of the first character that arrived following the wake-up.

You don't specify what baud rate you are using, but it may be possible to wire a small (and cheap) processor which has a very fast wake-up cycle between the device that's transmitting and your other processor.  That processor would sleep while it waits for a falling edge on its rx line.  Once it saw such an edge, it would output a 'wake-up' pulse and grab the first four data bits from its rx line.  It would then continue with receiving the next four data bits while it outputs the data it had received, at twice the baud rate.  The ultimate recipient of the data would receive its byte exactly when the transmitter finishes sending it, but could afford to spend 4.5 bit times at the old baud rate waking up without losing any data.

If one didn't want to have the device double the baud rate, one wouldn't have to--one could instead forward data with some delay.  Whether or not such a delay would pose a problem would be application-specific.  Note that if the device has a handshake wire from the CPU which will need the wake-up, the delay could be less than a character time, and could drop to almost nothing if the sender isn't transmitting absolutely continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Energymicro EFM32 MCUs - they are able to do exactly what you want.