# How to delay a signal?

Tags: uart

I need the RX line of my UART to be delayed about 1 ms, so I receive my data a fraction later. Are there simple, cheap components who can do this? Or would I need an extra external UART with a FIFO, etc.?

Comment: You could also consider sending the data 1ms later, or waiting 1ms before using the data - if you have access to the system of transmitter/receiver of course.

Comment: No, he's still trying to solve http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57920/wake-up-mcu-on-uart-rx-data . Though if the mystery peripheral implements hardware flow control, that could be used to provide the delay you suggest, as I added in a comment to my answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It implements hw flow control, but it only asserts the CTS line when its buffer is full, not when its sending data out.

Comment: @Joshua can you drive the CTS line from a software controlled discrete rather than the UART?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are simple to use digital delay lines.  Take a look at the [LTC6994-2](http://www.linear.com/docs/29725) for example.

An advantage of this approach over a microcontroller is that there is no code to maintain, no programming provisions to be accommodated. Just solder it and should just work, which is what I get the feeling would work best for you.

Comment: microcontroller is a versatile part for a parts bin.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you can use a delay line to delay your signal :)

[image: delay line]

Practically, you can use a small 6 pin PIC microcontroller to achieve your goal.

Comment: Is there anything you can't do with a 6 pin PIC! :)

Comment: @kenny True. Before that popularity was 8 pin Tiny11 for $0.25 :)